# How to update the property for all member baseline in UCM?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, baseline

We have composite baseline for our components.

Whenever we release the product after recommend the baseline, I would change the property of baseline to change the promotion level.

By default the promotion level is "`INITIAL`".
While we release the product i would change the Promotion property as "`EXTERNAL RELEASE`".

But to do this, I have to go and edit each any every member baseline property.
Is there any way to make changes in composite baseline properties to replicate in it's member?

Answer (score 2):

No, the re is no "inheritance" between the custom values of a composite baseline and its baseline member.

It is best to script the operation, by describing the composite baseline, extract the baseline members name, and do a `cleartool mkattr -replace` on each one with the new value.
(`cleartool mkattr` has a `-recurs` - recursive - option, but it would be for directory only, it doesn't work for non-file-system objects)

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%[depends_on]Cp\n" aCompositeBaseline@\aPVob
# for each member baselines
cleartool mkattr -replace PromotionLevel "EXTERNAL RELEASE" baseline:aBaseline@\aPVob
```

Note how I use the fully qualifed name of the object on which I want to modify the custom attribute value:  `baseline:aBaseline@\aPVob`.

Since "`EXTERNAL_RELEASE`" isn't a default promotion level, you need to define it first: see "[About creating custom promotion levels and attribute types for UCM baselines](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21135893)".

[image: Define Promotion Level]