# Finding the Latest Baseline in clearcase on which Rebase is not yet happned

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

We have created multiple `Development` streams under `Integration` and also have one `Deployment` stream.
When the developer will do the changes and any one of the `Dev` stream and create the Baseline on Int, it automatically triggers rebase on `Deploy` stream, then build and deployment will happen.

The issue here is how do I know which development steam created the baseline when I have *one* `deployment` stream for rebasing against, with many `Development` streams for build and deployment.

Is there any command to find the latest baseline created and on which still the rebasing is not happened?

Answer (score 0):

You have this I presume:

```
Int
|
-----Deployment
|
-----Dev1
|
-----Dev2
|
-----Dev3
```

You deliver to `Int`, then rebase to `Deployment`.

You know which baseline has just been rebased from `Int` (since a rebase simply replace the foundation baseline of `Depl` with one coming from `Int`)
But you don't know what that baseline on `Int` comes from `Dev`.

Simplest solution: if that baseline on Int is created *each time **one*** dev baseline is delivered: **naming convention**.
A proper baseline name can help you remember the dev baseline it comes from.

The problem with **rebase** is that, once you rebase on deployment, you don't know what was the baseline present on deployment just before the rebase.
That is why, in addition of a rebase, you need to update a metadata attached to, for instance, the Deployment stream object, in order to keep a list of the rebased baselines.
See as an example [`cleartool mkattr`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkattr.htm) illustrated in "[How to update the property for all member baseline in UCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12418738/6309)".